# Using three version (class, function, lambda) for setting logging Filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-internals

I can create the same Filter in three different ways:

1) As a lambda:

```
import logging
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.addFilter(lambda record: getattr(record, 'msg') == 'Hello')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.warning('ok!')
```

2) As a function:

```
def is_hello(record):
    return getattr(record, 'msg') == 'Hello'

import logging    
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.addFilter(is_hello)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.warning('ok!')
```

3) As a class

```
class LogFilter:
    def filter(self, record):
        return getattr(record, 'msg') == 'Hello'

import logging    
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.addFilter(LogFilter())
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.warning('ok!')
```

How does the loggin module allow such variation, does the filter do something like:

```
if callable(provider_filter):
    provider_filter(record)
else:
    provider_filter.filter(record)
```

Or how does it 'know' whether to call the function or to call one of the class methods?

Comment: Note, `getattr(record, 'msg') == 'Hello'` is an overengineered way of writing `record.msg == "hello"`. Also note, a `lambda` *is* a function. It is simply anonymous. That is it's only distinguishing feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yeah, it just checks if it has a `.filter` attribute, and if it doesn't it assumes it's a callable:

[Here is the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3b18b17efcee6f968cf85c543254b3611311e9f4/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L792):

```
def filter(self, record):
    """
    Determine if a record is loggable by consulting all the filters.
    The default is to allow the record to be logged; any filter can veto
    this and the record is then dropped. Returns a zero value if a record
    is to be dropped, else non-zero.
    .. versionchanged:: 3.2
       Allow filters to be just callables.
    """
    rv = True
    for f in self.filters:
        if hasattr(f, 'filter'):
            result = f.filter(record)
        else:
            result = f(record) # assume callable - will raise if not
        if not result:
            rv = False
            break
    return rv
```